# How to get a class file (in specification format) during runtime using JVMTI?

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, jvmti, jvm-bytecode

I am working on a research project which includes Hotspot profiler's feedback. Currently I am working on a JVMTI agent which should have following features:

1. listen any compiled load event.
2. Extract and analyse the complete class file which has hotspot method.
3. Modify/Redefine the bytecodes of the class.

I have a lot of API functions available in JVMTI to get the information about the class file having the method which is being compiled by JIT. However, I want the complete class file of the method as described in java virtual machine specification. 
If it is not possible to get a whole class file, I would at least want a class file in following format:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int               magic;
    unsigned short             minor_version;
    unsigned short             major_version;
    unsigned short             constant_pool_count;
    unsigned char             *constant_pool;
    unsigned short             access_flags;
    unsigned short             this_class;
    unsigned short             super_class;
    unsigned short             interfaces_count;
    unsigned char             *interfaces;
    unsigned short             fields_count;
    unsigned char             *fields;
    unsigned short             methods_count;
    unsigned char             *methods;
    unsigned short             attributes_count;
    unsigned char             *attributes;

}ClassFile;
```

I have following code so far which serves the purpose partially:

```
    void JNICALL compiled_method_load(jvmtiEnv *jvmti, jmethodID method, jint code_size, const void* code_addr, jint map_length, const jvmtiAddrLocationMap* map, const void* compile_info)
    {
    static ClassFile *clazz;
    jvmtiError err;
    jclass klass;
    jint constant_pool_count_pointer;
    jint constant_pool_byte_count_pointer;
    jint local_entry_count_ptr;
    jint minor, major;
    jint modifier_ptr;
    jvmtiLocalVariableEntry* table_ptr;

    unsigned char* constant_pool_bytes_ptr;

    char* name = NULL;
    char* signature = NULL;
    char* generic_ptr = NULL;
    unsigned char* bytecodes_ptr = NULL;

    err = (*jvmti)->RawMonitorEnter(jvmti,lock);
    check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "raw monitor enter");

        clazz->magic = 0xCAFEBABE;

        err = (*jvmti)->GetMethodDeclaringClass(jvmti,method, &klass);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Declaring Class");

        err = (*jvmti)->GetClassVersionNumbers(jvmti, klass, &minor, &major);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Class Version Number");

        clazz->minor_version = (u2_int)minor;
        clazz->major_version = (u2_int)major;

        err = (*jvmti)->GetConstantPool(jvmti, klass, &constant_pool_count_pointer,
                &constant_pool_byte_count_pointer, &constant_pool_bytes_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Constant Pool");

        clazz->constant_pool_count = constant_pool_count_pointer;
        clazz->constant_pool = constant_pool_bytes_ptr;

        err = (*jvmti)->GetClassModifiers(jvmti,klass, &modifier_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Access Flags");

        clazz->access_flags = (u2_int)modifier_ptr;


        err = (*jvmti)->GetBytecodes(jvmti,method, &code_size, &bytecodes_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Bytecodes");

        err = (*jvmti)->GetLocalVariableTable(jvmti,method, &local_entry_count_ptr, &table_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "Get Local Variable table");



    if (constant_pool_bytes_ptr != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti,(unsigned char*)constant_pool_bytes_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate bytecodes pointer");
    }
    if (bytecodes_ptr != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti,(unsigned char*)bytecodes_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate bytecodes pointer");
    }
    if (name != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti,(unsigned char*)name);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate name");
    }
    if (signature != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti,(unsigned char*)signature);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate signature");
    }
    if (generic_ptr != NULL) {
        err = (*jvmti)->Deallocate(jvmti,(unsigned char*)generic_ptr);
        check_jvmti_error(jvmti, err, "deallocate generic_ptr");
    }

    err = (*jvmti)->RawMonitorExit(jvmti,lock);
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to get complete class file through an agent?
2. If not, how can I fill the `ClassFile` structure using `JVMTI` or `JNI` API?
3. Any other strategy to achieve my objective?

**Limitations:**

1. I have to examine and manipulate bytecodes during runtime a long time after class loading. So AFAIK java agents using libraries like `ASM` and `JAVASSIST` wouldn't be of any help.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing up terms. ASM and JAVASSIST are just libraries, not agents. How you use them, i.e. during class loading or later-on, is up to you. But since you are writing native code, using libraries written in Java would be quite complicated anyway. Regarding your actual question, `ClassFileLoadHook`s will receive the byte code in the class file format. The fact that you want to get it for already loaded classes, is not so important, as, if you invoke `RetransformClasses`, the hooks will get called again for the specified classes.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I couldn't quite get what you said about my question though. My problem is not to get the bytecode only. I'm already doing that and it is in class file format: 
`(*jvmti)->GetBytecodes(jvmti,method, &code_size, &bytecodes_ptr);`



I want to get whole class file which has constant pool, interfaces, attributes etc as mentioned in the spec. 

Moreover, I don't wanna listen `ClassFileLoadHook`. I have a call back for `CompiledMethodLoad` event which needs to get all the class information. I hope it clears the premises of my problem.

Comment: `GetBytecodes` returns the byte code of a single method. So it’s not “in class file format”, well otherwise, what was the question? If you want to get the entire class file, `ClassFileLoadHook` is the way to go. As said above, when you call `RetransformClasses`, the hook will be called with the specified class immediately. That’s a way to get the class file right when you need it. It’s a bit complicated, but it’s the only way I know.

Comment: By the way, the `struct` you have defined is not an actual class file, it only has a structure that loosely resembles it. A real class file has no pointers and uses well defined big endian datatypes which do not necessarily match the runtime representation of `short` and `int` on your machine.

Comment: **First Comment**
Ok. I got it now. You want me to call a dummy `RetransformClasses` function so that I can get a `ClassFileLoadHook` which will provide me the whole class file. It would be a great help if you can please write a small demonstration as an answer so that I can test it.

Problem is I don't know how to provide `const jclass* classes` argument in the `RetransformClasses` function.

**Second Comment**
I know this `struct` is not a class file. I just wanted to have a work around since I thought that it was not possible to get the class file.

Comment: `jclass*` is just a pointer to a `jclass`, which could be an array, if you are interested in multiple classes. Since you are interested in only one class, you can pass a pointer to the `klass` variable, which already contains the desired `jclass` (after you called `GetMethodDeclaringClass`). So you pass `&klass` as `classes` and a `class_count` of `1` (one). That’s it. The last time, I wrote C code, is so long ago, you would need more time to fix my mistakes than to write it yourself.

Comment: Why should a `ClassFileLoadHook` invoke `RetransformClasses`? It is already the method responsible for transforming code, if intended. All it has to do, is to store a reference to the new (modified) byte code in the pointer passed as `new_class_data` parameter. Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#ClassFileLoadHook)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally got it working. The ideas from Holger in the comments are the main sources of this answer. I don't think anybody would need this, but just to answer it, here goes.

Simply put, to get the whole class file, there is only one possibility in `JVMTI` APIs and that is `ClassFileLoadHook` event. This event is triggered whenever a new class is being loaded in JVM or when `Retransformclasses` or `RedefineClasses` functions are called. So I called `Retransformclasses` function as a dummy call just to invoke `ClassFileLoadHookEvent` and then finally got the whole class.

Added following function in my source code mainly besides adding capabilities and callback setups:

```
void JNICALL
Class_File_Load_Hook(jvmtiEnv *jvmti_env,
            JNIEnv* jni_env,
            jclass class_being_redefined,
            jobject loader,
            const char* name,
            jobject protection_domain,
            jint class_data_len,
            const unsigned char* class_data,
            jint* new_class_data_len,
            unsigned char** new_class_data)
{
    jvmtiError err;
    unsigned char* jvmti_space = NULL;
    char* args = "vop";

    javab_main(3, args, class_data, class_data_len);

    err = (*jvmti_env)->Allocate(jvmti_env, (jlong)global_pos, &jvmti_space);
    check_jvmti_error(jvmti_env, err, "Allocate new class Buffer.");

    (void)memcpy((void*)jvmti_space, (void*)new_class_ptr, (int)global_pos);

    *new_class_data_len = (jint)global_pos;
    *new_class_data = jvmti_space;
}
```

The `class_data` variable here contains the complete class file on which the `ClassFileLoadHook` event was invoked. I analyzed this class file and instrumented it in a new `char*` array using `javab_main` method and finally pointed the new array towards `new_class_data` variable. The `new_class_ptr` is a global variable which contains the changed definition of the class.